# Error con draft.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo un error con draft.js

parece que no reconoce la definición de 'global' en node-modules

```
ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at node_modules/fbjs/lib/setImmediate.js (setImmediate.js:13:18)
    at __require (chunk-OMFGQDFA.js?v=37a6892b:8:50)
    at node_modules/draft-js/lib/editOnBeforeInput.js (editOnBeforeInput.js:27:20)
    at __require (chunk-OMFGQDFA.js?v=37a6892b:8:50)
    at node_modules/draft-js/lib/DraftEditorEditHandler.js (DraftEditorEditHandler.js:15:21)
    at __require (chunk-OMFGQDFA.js?v=37a6892b:8:50)
    at node_modules/draft-js/lib/DraftEditor.react.js (DraftEditor.react.js:36:30)
    at __require (chunk-OMFGQDFA.js?v=37a6892b:8:50)
    at node_modules/draft-js/lib/Draft.js (Draft.js:28:19)
    at __require (chunk-OMFGQDFA.js?v=37a6892b:8:50)
```

aqui esta el codigo en el que estoy usando el draft.js

importo el use state para crear un estado que guarde el valor del editor para luego poder guardarlo o usarlo, despues importo el editor de draft.js

y estoy usando tailwind css para los estilos del editor

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { Editor } from "draft-js"
export default function Contenido (){
    const [value, setValue] = useState(null)


    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setValue(e.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <Editor value={value} readOnly={false} onChange={handleChange} className='w-full h-full bg-transparent resize-none outline-none text-white border-white border-2 placeholder:text-white text-lg ' placeholder='Escribe aqui...'/>
        
    )
}
```

Comment: Podrías incluir la forma en que estas haciendo las importaciones en el componente Contenido.jsx ??

Comment: listo ya he hecho la actualizacion

Comment: Al parecer falta una configuración adicional. [Acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65586906/react-and-electron-with-draft-js-global-is-not-defined) te dejo una posible solución :D

Comment: **muchas gracias**

Comment: esta respuesta la saque de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65586906/react-and-electron-with-draft-js-global-is-not-defined global pasó a llamarse globalThis en la propuesta tc39 https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/issues/290 solo agregue esto a index.html así es como lo arreglé ```
<script> const global = globalThis;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

esta respuesta la saque de

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65586906/react-and-electron-with-draft-js-global-is-not-defined

global pasó a llamarse globalThis en la propuesta tc39 https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/issues/290

solo agregue esto a index.html así es como lo arreglé

```
<script>
      const global = globalThis;
</script>
```

Comment: Excelente práctica el dar la solución a tu pregunta. +1